# image size not taking local parameters - using height:auto from different file

Tags: html, css

When I look at the inspector I see this controlling my image size (from a css file in a template (joomla))

```
img {
border: 0 none;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

if I remove the height: auto; the image goes to exactly the size I want it to go to

how do I override this?
I place the image in a div

```
#dealdataimage
{
  width:100px !important;
   height:100px !important;
}
```

and also placed the height width within the html

```
 <div id="dealdataimage">
   <img src="gohere" alt="deal image" height="100" width="100" />
</div>
```

yet in the inspector the image is 400 x 689 (size of the file)

Comment: First there is an error in your CSS code, as `dealdataimage` is no valid HTML element name. And I guess that it is also another error in your original files that causes the trouble. Have you validated your HTML + CSS files? And try inline CSS, like `<img src="http://[path-to-image-resource]" alt="deal image" style="height:100px; width:100px;" />`.

Comment: yes - code is valid - assumed people could decifer it was within a div...

Comment: If you're using `dealdataimage {}` for your css as a class it needs to be `.dealdataimage {}`.  If it's the div or img id, then it should be `#dealdataimage {}`.

Comment: @dcclassics that was it - is withouth the # acceptable? It didn't show an error on the console

Comment: See my answer below.  It wouldn't error, but I don't believe it would validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#dealdataimage
{
  width:100px !important;
   height:100px !important;
}
```

You need to add the `#` for the div ID.  Otherwise it's looking for an html element `<dealdataimage>`

Comment: the height:auto if I uncheck it in the inspector makes it go to exactly what I set

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I can try explaining a few things.  If you're using width:100px and height:100px, it's only being applied to the div, and the img will scale with its own proportions to the div.  It won't scale height and width.  You could do `#dealdataimage img { width: 100px; height:100px; }` to make your image those proportions.

Comment: ^ that was the issue
I needed it to be applied to the img AND was missing the #
otherwise the img properties were being used from the stardard joomla css img